# Grails service mongodb

Tags: grails, mongodb, service, groovy, grails-orm

Using mongodb in grails i am trying to get a hold of the database from a service in the same fashion as when connecting to it from a controller.

e.g

```
static mongo
    def db = mongo.getDB("dbone")
```

this does not seem to work. Is there a way to get a hold of the database from within a service in some other fasion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a 'static' variable which is incorrect. Try 'def mongo'

Comment: this did take care of the problem! However i am having the problem that the service is continuously establishing new connections to the database for each new entry, is this the mongodb way or is there a way to "solv" this ?